# How to register a key in the IORegistry and react to its change in the kext?

Tags: macos, iokit, kernel-extension

I am studying kext development. I'm trying to implement a simple "generic" kext that would publish a key in the IORegistry and react to its changes then.
The class is quite trivial, it just registers with IOService::registerPowerDriver and publish a key. Reading some book, I've found following:

> When a driver’s property is set from a user space application, the method setProperties() in the corresponding driver object is called with a parameter containing a dictionary of the properties that have been set.

So, I implemented it like that:

Header:

```
#define ENABLED_PROP_NAME "Enabled"

class GenericPower : public IOService
{
    OSDeclareDefaultStructors(GenericPower);

public:
    virtual bool init(OSDictionary* dict) override;
    virtual IOService* probe(IOService* provider, SInt32* score) override;
    virtual void free(void) override;
    virtual bool start(IOService* provider) override;
    virtual void stop(IOService * provider) override;
    virtual IOReturn setProperties(OSObject* properties) override;

protected:

    virtual IOReturn        powerStateWillChangeTo(IOPMPowerFlags capabilities, unsigned long stateNumber, IOService* whatDevice) override;
    virtual IOReturn        setPowerState(unsigned long powerStateOrdinal, IOService* whatDevice) override;
    virtual IOReturn        powerStateDidChangeTo(IOPMPowerFlags capabilities, unsigned long stateNumber, IOService* whatDevice) override;

    void updateProperties(void);

private:
    // Property to publish:
    bool isEnabled = true;
};
```

CPP:

```
#define super IOService

OSDefineMetaClassAndStructors(GenericPower, super);

bool GenericPower::init(OSDictionary* dict)
{
    if (!super::init(dict)) {
        IOLog("GenericPower: init failed\n");
        return (false);
    }
    IOLog("GenericPower: init\n");

    return (true);
}

void GenericPower::free(void)
{
    IOLog("GenericPower: free\n");

    super::free();
}

IOService* GenericPower::probe(IOService* provider, SInt32* score)
{
    IOLog("GenericPower: probe\n");

    return (super::probe(provider, score));
}


IOReturn GenericPower::setProperties(OSObject* properties)
{
    IOLog("GenericPower: setProperties\n");

    if (properties == nullptr) {
        IOLog("GenericPower: setProperties: no properties\n");
        return (kIOReturnUnsupported);
    }

    OSDictionary* propertiesDict;
    propertiesDict = OSDynamicCast(OSDictionary, properties);
    if (propertiesDict == nullptr) {
        IOLog("GenericPower: setProperties: cannot get properties\n");
        return (kIOReturnUnsupported);
    }
    OSObject * rawValue = propertiesDict->getObject(ENABLED_PROP_NAME);
    OSBoolean * boolValue = OSDynamicCast(OSBoolean, rawValue);
    if (boolValue == nullptr) {
        IOLog("GenericPower: setProperties: cannot get \"" ENABLED_PROP_NAME "\" property\n");
    } else {
        IOLog("GenericPower: setProperties: new value %s\n", boolValue->getValue() ? "Enabled" : "Disabled");
        isEnabled = boolValue->getValue();
    }

    IOLog("GenericPower: setProperties: \"" ENABLED_PROP_NAME "\" set to %s\n", isEnabled ? "ON" : "OFF");

    updateProperties();

    return (kIOReturnSuccess);
}

enum {
    kPowerStateOff,
    kPowerStateSleep,
    kPowerStateOn,
//
    kNumPowerStates
};

static IOPMPowerState powerStates[kNumPowerStates] = {
    {
        // Off
        kIOPMPowerStateVersion1,          // version
        0,   // capabilityFlags
        0,                      // outputPowerCharacter
        0,                      // inputPowerRequirement
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    },
    {
        // Sleep
        kIOPMPowerStateVersion1,          // version
        kIOPMSleepCapability,   // capabilityFlags
        kIOPMSleep,                      // outputPowerCharacter
        kIOPMSleep,                      // inputPowerRequirement
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    },
    {
        // On
        kIOPMPowerStateVersion1,          // version
        kIOPMPowerOn | kIOPMDeviceUsable,   // capabilityFlags
        kIOPMPowerOn,                      // outputPowerCharacter
        kIOPMPowerOn,                      // inputPowerRequirement
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    },
};

bool GenericPower::start(IOService* provider)
{
    if (!super::start(provider)) {
        IOLog("GenericPower: start: IOService start error\n");
        return (false);
    }

    PMinit();
    provider->joinPMtree(this);
    registerPowerDriver(this, powerStates, kNumPowerStates);

    makeUsable();
    registerService();

    updateProperties();

    return (true);
}
void GenericPower::stop(IOService* provider)
{
    IOLog("GenericPower: stop. isEnabled=%d\n", (int)isEnabled);

    PMstop();
    super::stop(provider);
}

// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

IOReturn GenericPower::powerStateWillChangeTo(IOPMPowerFlags capabilities, unsigned long stateNumber, IOService* whatDevice)
{
    IOLog("GenericPower: powerStateWillChangeTo %lu\n", stateNumber);
    return (kIOPMAckImplied);
}

IOReturn GenericPower::setPowerState(unsigned long powerStateOrdinal, IOService* whatDevice)
{
    IOLog("GenericPower: setPowerState %lu\n", powerStateOrdinal);

    return (kIOPMAckImplied);
}

IOReturn GenericPower::powerStateDidChangeTo(IOPMPowerFlags capabilities, unsigned long stateNumber, IOService* whatDevice)
{
    IOLog("GenericPower: powerStateDidChangeTo %lu\n", stateNumber);
    return (kIOPMAckImplied);

}
void GenericPower::updateProperties(void)
{
    // Properties init
    OSBoolean * osProp = OSBoolean::withBoolean(isEnabled);
    setProperty(ENABLED_PROP_NAME, osProp);
    OSSafeReleaseNULL(osProp);
}
```

But when I try to change this key in the ioregistryExplorer.app, I observe no call for IOService::setProperties in the log at all. Please help - how could I publish the key and react to its changes in the kext? Cannot find any relevant docs and/or examples.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is most likely that *IORegistryExplorer.app* doesn't support setting properties on I/O Registry entries. To verify if this is the case, I suggest writing a very small command line utility which locates your kext's service node, for example using [`IOServiceGetMatchingService()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1514535-ioservicegetmatchingservice?language=objc), and then sets the property using [`IORegistryEntrySetCFProperty()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1514882-ioregistryentrysetcfproperty?language=objc). You should then see the call to the `setProperties()` method happen.

Comment: Oh my! 
You're right! Absolutely correct! Made a simple 5-line program and it sets everything just like expected. Why did I think IORegistryExplorer should set it as well... Questions, questions...
Thank you so much!